# Completely remove "messages maintainer:" from Vim?

Tags: ex-mode, message

I don't want to see this `messages maintainer:` message every time I open `:messages`.

Is there a way to remove the `messages maintainer:`  line from messages?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a simple way to get rid of that message. Use a locale that Vim doesn't know.

For example, I am using `LANG=C.UTF-8` and I don't see this message:

```
LANG=C.UTF-8 vim -c ':mess'
[empty]
```

Answer (score 0):

The feature [doesn't appear](https://github.com/vim/vim/blob/master/src/message.c#L1097-L1104) to be governed by any option, runtime flag, or compiler flag.

You *might* be able to get rid of that message by editing the source and compiling Vim yourself but the whack-a-mole potential is strong with this… and you would have to maintain your own fork. Meh.

Comment: Yeah I agree. A nuclear option. But I do find it weird that Bam put his name and email is a place people look at quite often... with no option to turn it off.